# How to avoid page reload when i select dropdown list ?? and also how to get selected values php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am stuck with small problem.
    when i change my drop down list the page is getting reloaded.
    Can any one  help me .
    This code is used to retrieve userid, based on userid get all the application id form drop down and populate it into dropdown list.
    If i select value in drop down  i am storing selected value
    Here is my code.

```
<?php
    $selected = " ";
    function get_options($select) {
        global $wpdb;
        $user_ID = get_current_user_id();

        echo $user_ID;

        $sql = $wpdb->get_col("select Application_ID from wp3_cteTest where $user_ID = userid");
        echo $sql;

        //print_r($keysql);

        $options = "";
        while (list($k, $v) = each($sql)) {
            if ($select == $v) {
                $options.='<option value="' . $v . '" selected>' . $v . '</option>';
            } else {
                $options.='<option value="' . $v . '">' . $v . '</option>';
            }
        }
        return $options;
    }

    if (isset($_POST['applications'])) {
        $selected = $_POST['applications'];
        echo $selected;
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <?php $default_state = 'please Select your id'; ?>
            <select name="applications" onchange=this.form.submit()>
                <option value=' ' ><?php echo $default_state ?></option>
                <?php echo get_options($selected) ?>
            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I Tried removing form, if i remove form drop down doesn't work, I wont get selected value.
    Then what is wrong??
    Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you don't want to submit form by just changing the selecbox?

Comment: @Maha Dev I want on change and get the value of that drop down without submit

Answer (score 3):

You've got `onchange=this.form.submit()` in your select tag, so when you change the option selected javascript is submitting the form.

Just change...

```
<select name="applications" onchange=this.form.submit()>
```

...to...

```
<select name="applications">
```

Comment: if i remove onchange will not get the values.

Comment: PHP only runs server side, so If you want to use the value in php it will need to reload the page, if you don't want to reload the page you'll need to use ajax

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    function getval(sel) {
  var get= sel.value
       alert(get);
  
 var a=get;  //variable you want pass

 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
     alert( xhttp.responseText)
     }
 };

xhttp.open("GET", "a="+a, false);
 xhttp.send();
 }
</script>

<?php echo $_GET['a']?>  But still not getting echoed

Comment: @JMR What is it that you want to do with the value once you've got it?

Comment: Based on that value I am going to insert upload file into database

Comment: It's likely that you don't need the value as a PHP variable at this stage. Is the file upload field going to be in the same form as your select? If so you can just submit it along with the file. If your file upload form is on a different page you can just submit this form to your upload page.

Comment: @Brookesias thanks for the suggestion... I will try to implement the logic you have given......

Comment: According to you on click of upload button ,get the application I'd  from  drop down and insert that ...am I right with the logic

Comment: Essentially yes, it's difficult to say exactly how it will work without knowing the specifics of your upload form, but if it's in the same form as your select when the form is submitted the page will have the value in $_POST['applications']

Answer (score 0):

So if you just need the selected id without submit the form then replace this line:

```
<select name="applications" onchange=this.form.submit()>
```

with this :

```
<select name="applications" onchange="getval(this)">
```

and Add little script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getval(sel) {
       alert(sel.value);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I thought to avoid script because I don't know how to get javascript variable with php  variable $

Comment: In future I will be using this variable for upload and download form which is in php

Comment: Ok if you don't want to use javascript then remove the onchange event and add a submit button. Select any option in dropdown and submit it!

Comment: Can't we get values without submit button and script in php

Comment: No! if you want that value then you need to use Javascript. No any other solution

Comment: Ok thanks bro...I will try it once....if you know how to get javascript variable to php variable ...please suggest me it will help me a lot